# Solve IVP using Laplace Transforms: $y'' + 4y' + 5y = \delta(t-1), y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

I have the following problem
$$y'' + 4y' + 5y = \delta(t-1),\quad y(0) = 0,\quad y'(0) = 3$$
When transforming I get
$$s^2Y - sy(0) - y'(0) + 4(sY - y(0)) + 5Y = e^{-s} \\
Y(s^2 + 4s +5) = e^{-s} + 3 \\
Y(s) = \frac{e^{-s} + 3}{s^2 + 4s + 5}$$
Now, I rewrote $s^2 + 4s +5 = (s + 2)^2 + 1$ 
$$Y(s) = e^{-s}\left( \frac{1}{(s+2)^2 + 1} \right) + 
3\left( \frac{1}{(s+2)^2 + 1}\right)$$
And transforming back I use the fact that 
$e^{at}\sin{bt} = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{(s-a)^2 + b^2}\right)$ thus I get
$$y(t) = \delta(t-1) e^{-2t}\sin{t} + 3e^{-2t}\sin{t}$$
But this I get something else when wolfram solves the equation. And when plotting my solution it seems wierd. Can anyone check if there's anything wrong here?

Sorry about the formatting, couldn't get it to line up..

Comment: Is the equation $y'' + 4y' + 5 = \delta(t-1)$ or $y'' + 4y' + 5y = \delta(t-1)$?

Comment: $5y$, sorry about that

Comment: when you wrote $s^2Y - sy(0) - y'(0) + 4(Y - y(0)) + 5Y = e^{-s} $ the following step is $Y=\dfrac{e^{-s}+3}{s^2+9}$

Comment: Oh, well, I forgot to put an $s$ there.

Comment: Actually $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(e^{-s}Y(s)\right)$ gives $\theta(t-1)f(t)$ where $\theta(t)$ is Heaviside theta function equal to $0$ for $t<0 $ and $1$ for $t>0$. Therefore your result should be $$y(t)=e^{-2 t} \theta (t-1) \sin (t-1)+3 e^{-2 t} \sin (t)$$

Comment: Thanks, that gives the correct answer. But i thought $u(t-1) = \frac{e^{-s}}{s}$

Comment: Yes, it is. But $u(t-1)\cdot f(t)$ gives $e^{-s}F(s)$

Comment: @Raffaele In regard to your previous comment, note that $u(t-1)\cdot \color{red}{f(t-1)}$ gives $e^{-s}F(s)$, as stated on result **27** on the following [table](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf). Consequently, it follows that you are missing an $e^2$ in your result, which I also show in my answer below:
$$y(t)=\color{red}{e^2}\cdot e^{-2t}\theta(t-1)\sin(t-1)+3e^{-2t}\sin(t)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start off from the last point where you were on the right track:
$$Y(s) = \color{red}{e^{-s}\left( \frac{1}{(s+2)^2 + 1} \right)} + 
\color{green}{3\left( \frac{1}{(s+2)^2 + 1}\right)}$$
The only mistake you made is when evaluating the Inverse Laplace transform of the red part, as shown below:

---

> In this answer, we prove the following result (Result **27** on the [Table of Laplace Transforms](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf)):
>   $$\mathcal{L}\{u_c(t)\cdot f(t-c)\}=e^{-cs}F(s) \tag{1}$$
>   Where $F(s)=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$ and [$u_c(t)=u(t-c)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). This is often referred to as the *Second Shifting Theorem*.

By definition, we must consider the following improper integral:
$$\begin{align} \mathcal{L}\{u_c(t)f(t-c)\}&=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}u_c(t)f(t-c)~dt\\&=\int_c^{\infty} e^{-st}f(t-c)~dt \end{align}$$
Using the change of variable $y=t-c$, we obtain:
$$\int_c^{\infty} e^{-st}f(t-c)~dt=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-s(y+c)}f(y)~dy=e^{-cs} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-sy}f(y)~dy=e^{-cs}F(s) \tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

---

Using $(1)$, and selecting $c=1$, we clearly see that the Inverse Laplace transform of the red part is:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{e^{-s}}{(s+2)^2+1}\right\}=u_1(t)\cdot e^{-2(t-1)}\sin(t-1)=e^{2-2t} u(t-1)\sin(t-1)$$
The answer you obtain will indeed be the same as [Wolfram Alpha's answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2B4y%27%2B5y%3DDiracDelta%5Bt-1%5D;+y(0)%3D0;+y%27(0)%3D3), namely:
$$y(t)=e^{2-2t}u(t-1)\sin(t-1)+3e^{-2t}\sin(t)$$